# How is BigQuery slot quota calculated?

Tags: google-bigquery

We are considering moving to flat rate pricing for BigQuery, but it is unclear from the documentation how slot utilization is computed.

You pay for flat rate with a monthly rate, and if I look at out our slot utlization over a month in Stack driver it is consistently reported under 500 slots. But if I change to graphing out the daily utilization we sometimes peak over 2000 slots.

So is the allocated slots we are allowed to use measured against average or peak usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allocated slots are counted against peak usage. With a 500 slot quota you can never utilize more than 500 slots at the same time. The result is that your query takes longer to run.